# Matching phone number in HashMap : Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am doing an application where I need to store some numbers and when someone call on phone I need to check if incoming number is present in my database or not.

***What I did***

I stored phone numbers in shared preferences. *Internally android uses Map for this purpose.*

***Problem:***

Lets say I stored 9089889899 (10 digit phone number). Now if I get an incoming call from this number it may BroadcastReceiver having 09089889899 or +91-9089889899 number for the same.

*So my problem is that if I stored a number into preferences then how can I match the incoming number is present in preferences or not.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use something like [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) to handle the phone numbers independent of the format.

There is also some functions for formatting and comparing numbers in [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html).

Comment: Can you provide some tutorials about how can I match two numbers using libphonenumber?

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences settings;
settings = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//for get sharepref
String phone = settings.getString("9089889899", 0);

//strPhone = has your broadcast receive number

if(strPhone.contains(phone)){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the mobile phone as key for the sharedpreference you can:

1. retrive all the values of your sharedpreference: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29)
2. iterate through the key set : see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)
3. for every key use the contains String method: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Edit: why are you not use a content provider?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the following code in your BroadCast Receiver.
here "abc" with the name of your Shared Perefence. Assuming that num here is the number you got from the Broadcast Receiver:
In the code,  the last 10 digits are taken out and compared, as these are what stored in SharedPreference.

```
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("abc",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    HashMap< String, String>hMap = (HashMap<String, String>) sp.getAll();
    String num = "+91-9089889899";

 if(   hMap.containsValue(num.substring(num.length()-10))){
     System.out.println("number present");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the regex that will match all the phone formats

```
(((([0-9]){0,1})(([0-9]){10}))|([0-9]){10}|(\+([0-9]){1,2}([0-9]{10})))
```

first part matches 0 - 1231231234
second part matches 1231231234
last part +91 - 1231231234

**update**

actually this is much better

```
(((([0-9]){0,1})(([0-9]){10}))|(\+([0-9]){1,2}([0-9]{10})))
```